# Difference between a.add(b) and a+=b as well as a=a+b?

Tags: solidity

For example, if I have:

```
balances[from] -= tokens;
balances[from] = balances[from]-tokens;
balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
```

What is a difference and why should I use one rather than the other, and when ?

Edit: I am aware of differences in languages such as C, but I don't know about the Solidity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two examples are using different syntax to accomplish the same task and will compile to identical bytecode. The third approach performs the calculation by using the [SafeMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) library.

Solidity has no built-in [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) protection. In the first two examples, if the value of `tokens` exceeds that of `balance[from]`, the subtraction would cause `balance[from]` to underflow. SafeMath adds a `require (balance[from] >= tokens)` check before performing the subtraction, which reverts the transaction when an underflow would occur.

To learn more about how SafeMath works and how to implement it in your contracts, I suggest reading [SafeMath to Protect from Overflows](https://ethereumdev.io/safemath-protect-overflows/).

Comment: OpenZeppelin documentation on SafeMath: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/utilities#math

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin

Comment: The third approach is using the SafeMath library, not implementing it.